# Binding Expression error: WPF renames object with Wrapped_ prefix

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm trying to fix the following binding expression error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisDetailDisDetailsIndicationQcVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''Wrapped_PrescriptionIndicationViewModel_e11b513f9a5b45059c1351597f748b73' (HashCode=33509524)'. BindingExpression:Path=DisDetailDisDetailsIndicationQcVisibility; DataItem='Wrapped_PrescriptionIndicationViewModel_e11b513f9a5b45059c1351597f748b73' (HashCode=33509524); target element is 'PrescriptionIndicationView' (Name='UserControl'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

Why is WPF (or maybe Prism) renaming the view model in this error message by prefixing it with "Wrapped_" and appending a Guid? Obviously this is not the correct name, so the obvious error is telling me it cannot find it. So my question is: Why is it looking in this object?

Here is the XAML in the view:

```
<Views1:PrescriptionIndicationView TabIndex="155"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=PrescriptionIndication, Converter={local:ViewModelValueConverter}}"
        Visibility="{Binding IndicationsVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
        x:Uid="50a00e5b462e43988b7d4c91332b0c6e">
</Views1:PrescriptionIndicationView>
```

Comment: WPF does not do that name wrapping.  At least, it never has in any of my WPF code.  It must be Prism doing it.

Comment: Use Snoop to figure out what's going on at runtime.

Comment: Can you show us how you defined your binding? Is that in xaml or code behind?